# Pandas Groupby a List of dictionaries to one dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am working on a problem where list of dictionaries have same keys and I want to aggregate all the values into a list for every key.

```
    x = [
    {'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Fyre', 'email': 'tom_f@gmail'},
    {'firstName': 'Jerry', 'lastName': 'Brat', 'email': 'jerry_b@gmail'},
    {'firstName': 'Phil', 'lastName': 'Hughes', 'email': 'phil_h@gmail'}
]
```

I want to convert above list of dictionaries to one dictionary which looks like:

```
    results = {
        'firstName': ['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Phil'],
        'lastName': ['Fyre', 'Brat', 'Hughes'],
        'email': ['tom_f@gmail', 'jerry_b@gmail', 'phil_h@gmail']
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `orient='list'`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x)
print (df1)
           email firstName lastName
0    tom_f@gmail       Tom     Fyre
1  jerry_b@gmail     Jerry     Brat
2   phil_h@gmail      Phil   Hughes

results = df1.to_dict(orient='list')
print (results)
{'firstName': ['Tom', 'Jerry', 'Phil'], 
'email': ['tom_f@gmail', 'jerry_b@gmail', 'phil_h@gmail'], 
'lastName': ['Fyre', 'Brat', 'Hughes']}
```